# How get Data from table in angular or submit a table data

Tags: html, angular, typescript, input, html-table

`I want fill these inputs in table after that wanna save them in database. I want to use for each loop to get all these inputs in type scripts please help me how to do that`
[image]

can we use j query for that purpose
[I check this question but I do not under stand    specially var app = angular.module('plunker', []);](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33997341/angular-submitting-table-with-data)

what is angular variable in his case

Answer (score 0):

I used FormArray concept to achieve this